# How can I find where a JavaScript function is defined in Firefox Quantum's debugger?

Tags: javascript, firefox, javascript-debugger

If I know the name of a JavaScript function, or if I have a reference to a function (eg. in a callback) how can I find where that function is defined, when using the Firefox Quantum debugger.

In Firebug/Firefox debugger I used to be able to type the function name into the JS console, and it would print a little bit of info and I could click on that output and be taken to the function definition.

Now in Firefox Quantum if I click on the function name it expands in the console to show info about the function object.

[image]

The Chrome debugger still works the way Firebug/Firefox used to, but I end up needing to debug/test in both browsers.

Answer (score 8):

In your debugger tab hit `ctrl + shift + f`.
This will open a search window where you can type in the funtion name.
This way you will get every location the name appears. Now you just have to look out for a line like: `function <name> () {`

Or you type `function <name>` right away.

Comment: This will work for global level functions, but falls short for things like methods inside of objects, or for anonymous functions passed in a callback.

Answer (score 1):

One roundabout trick you can use is to first dump the function definition to the console:

```
geometa_map_new_map_init.toString();
```

The output may look something like this:

```
function(coords, options) {
  // Some comment
  if(some_logic == true)
    do logic here
  else
    do other logic there
  // Here's a very specific comment
  var peculiar_name = 'some random string';
}
```

Notice that "`geometa_map_new_map_init`" does not appear in this *possible* definition as there are ways to define named functions other than the typical `function <name>` method.  If any particular line looks unique enough, like "`Here's a very specific comment`" or "`var peculiar_name`" you can try searching for one of those lines in your source code.  E.g., if you're in the base directory of your project on a linux machine you could run:

```
grep -l -R --exclude-dir=\.git "Here's a very specific comment" .|more
```

(The `--exclude-dir` part tells grep to not search the version control data in the `.git` directory, if one exists.)

If a file containing the line is found, open it up, search its contents, and you may find the function definition you're looking for, which might be defined in a way like:

```
geometa_map_new_map_init: function(coords, options) {
  // Some comment
  if(some_logic == true)
    do logic here
  else
    do other logic there
  // Here's a very specific comment
  var peculiar_name = 'some random string';
}
```

In this example, we discover that the function is actually defined as part of an object, hence the `<name>: function` syntax.